# Can we create SQL Server connection from DBVisualiser using existing SQL JDBC driver?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, dbvisualizer

I am new to DBvisualiser. I am working on private laptop, installed SQL Server Management Studio 18 and DBVisualiser. In SQL Server the connection is not encrypted and using windows authentication. TCP/IP enabled.

[image: SQL Server]

IN DBVisualizer I am using existing driver - JDBC

[image: DBVIsualiser connection]

[image]

I get error

> failed to login for user -***

what is missing here?

Comment: When you enter `Database Userid` and `Database Password` into DBVisualizer you're telling it to use SQL Login Authentication. If you want to use Windows Authentication simply leave those fields blank.

Comment: I still get same error