SQL Server with DB Visualizer
I know it may sound duplicate to other posts, but I have tried my best and still no luck.
The closest post that I found is the following: JDBC connection failed, error: TCP/IP connection to host failed
So my question is, I am using SQL Server 2022, and I am able to connect through SSMS, but if I want to use DBVisualizer to connect with it, then it fails.
As suggested in the aforementioned post, I did the following.

I turn off the firewall, so firewall must not be an issue anymore.
I did turn on the port, as the following picture shown.



For the dynamic port, I did the following.



As indicated in the post, somebody said that the dynamic port got to be the same with IPAll, I tried it, no luck.

So my DBVisualizer looks like the following. And I did set encrypted: Optional and trustServerCertificate: true in the properties column.




While my SSMS looks like the following. I am using Windows Authentication anyway.




Hope somebody helps, thank you for your time.
EDIT:
I am using jTDS, picture attached:


Are you using the jTDS driver that ships with DbVisualizer? Ref: Using SQL Server Single-Sign-On or Windows Authentication

@AlwaysLearning, I think I am using that, I have edited the post with latest screenshot, thanks.

@AlwaysLearning, by the way, I think this post somehow has the problem as mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993716/can-we-create-sql-server-connection-from-dbvisualiser-using-existing-sql-jdbc-dr

You're using the Microsoft JDBC Driver. If you want to use Windows Authentication with DbVisualizer you'll need to try using the third party jTDS driver as mentioned in the link in my previous comment.

@AlwaysLearning shouldn't it be possible to use Ms driver with their own windows auth dll? Jtds doesn't support tds 9 or whatever it's called so encryption won't work with it and sql server 2022

There's no need to use the old hat jtds server in 2024.
I installed db viz and followed the below procedure to create a windows auth connection:

Double click on the sql server in the connection list
Changed database to master, default was Northwind
Under properties, you need to change:


encrypt to false (or fix the correct keys, which is a hassle)
integratedSecurity = true (this actives windows auth)
I didn't need it, but sometimes you also need trustServerCertificate = true
The url should look like jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=master



Connect:



The user @AlwaysLearning already says it all:
First, go to download jTDS - SQL Server driver. Paste those files into the Driver Manager, picture attached:

You may need to create another User Drivers as it shall already have the default SQL Server by DBVisualizer, in my case, I make it like SQL Server-1.
Now the crucial part is to copy the ntlmauth.dll file from the downloaded folder (x64>SSO>ntlmauth.dll) to the correct path.
The correct path is: C:\Windows\System32. Restart the DBVisualizer, type the Database URL to be jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/pubs, where pubs is the database to be replaced with, and you should be good.
PANIC SITUATION:
If I disconnect the SQL Server-1 and reconnect again, I will get the I/O error like I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.
The way I overcome this difficulty is silly: simply close the DBVisualizer and open it again. Not sure if somebody can fix this panic situation.
